# Detect geolocation change in real time using WatchPosition

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm building an app using Capacitor and I want to use Geolocation.watchPosition to calculate the distance to a certain point in real time. The problem is that I don't know how to use the watch and update the distance when the device moves.

I can get the starting values when the app starts using a useEffect as done below:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@capacitor/geolocation';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Home = () => {
  const [currLat, setCurrLat] = useState(0);
  const [currLong, setCurrLong] = useState(0);

  const [watchLat, setWatchLat] = useState(0);
  const [watchLong, setWatchLong] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function CurrentPos() {
      const m = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
      setCurrLat(m.coords.latitude);
      setCurrLong(m.coords.longitude);
    }
    CurrentPos();

    async function WatchPos() {
      const ret = await Geolocation.watchPosition(
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 3000 },
        (pos) => {
          if (pos?.coords.latitude) setWatchLat(pos.coords.latitude);
          if (pos?.coords.longitude) setWatchLong(pos.coords.longitude);
        }
      );
    }
    WatchPos();
  }, []);

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonCard>
        <p>WatchPos: </p>
        <p>{watchLat}</p>
        <p>{watchLong}</p>
      </IonCard>
      <IonCard>
        <p>CurrPos: </p>
        <p>{currLat}</p>
        <p>{currLong}</p>
      </IonCard>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I guess I should set up a useEffect with lat and long values in the dependency array somehow, but how to achieve that with an async function?